# rails generate model Investor - getting error "The name 'Investor' is either already used..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have an almost new setup of ROR 3.1 here and have already generated 2 models (AdminUser and Advisor), when i try to add another model "Investor" I am getting this error:

> "The name 'Investor' is either already used in your application or
>   reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this
>   generator again."

I am using command: ***rails g model Investor***.
I have only two models in my project right now and non of them is called Investor...

**FIXED:**
It turned out that my application is called "Investor"; when I created rails app I did: rails new investor. I had to rename all the occurrences of the name of my app to a different name and it works now.

Here is a list of files you have to change:

- config.ru
- Rakefile
- config/application.rb
- config/environment.rb
- config/environments/development.rb
- config/environments/test.rb
- config/routes.rb
- config/initializers/secret_token.rb
- config/initializers/session_store.rb

Comment: I think it happens because i have my application called "Investor", i need to change the name of my app now...damn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happened because my application was called "Investor" (same as the model I wanted to add), once I've changed my application name it started to work...

Comment: Thanks for answering this and listing the files you need to change.  It's kind of dumb that this happens, though, as it's quite likely that one's application name is also going to end up being a model in the application!